# Java file upload : The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: java, file, file-upload, byte, inputstream

We have a tool where files can be uploaded.
The tool takes the following as input to upload a file:

Method signature:

```
uploadAttachmentOnXyz(<irrelevant> , byte[] attachmentData, ContentType contentType, String fileName)
```

In our code, we are trying to upload the files to that tool using that API. Behaviour:

1. PDF uploaded successfully and can be downloaded from tool.
2. docx uploaded successfully and can be downloaded.
3. For txt file, it gets uploaded successfully. But when I download file from tool it has additional characters:

```
----------------------------754900090813043831886410
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="upload.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

upload on sim test
----------------------------754900090813043831886410--
```

4. For image, the API uploads file on tool without error. But when I go on tool to download the image, it cannot be viewed or downloaded with the following message `The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors`

I suspect it is something to do with File/inputstream conversion to byte[]. NOTE: verified content type and it is right. I tried multiple approaches but still facing issue with image upload.. need help with this. Let me share the approaches:

1. File as input and used  FileUtils.readFileToByteArray to convert:

public boolean uploadAttachment(File file) throws Exception {

```
        byte[] filebytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
```

2. InputSteam and IOUtils.toByteArray

```
byte[] filebytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInputStream);
```

I tried 3/4 other approaches as well but with all these, behaviour is that image gets uploaded without error but when accessing it - it displays `The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors`

Need your inputs and help as I am stuck with this.

Thanks a ton.

Expecting: Image file should be uploaded with errors and should not display `The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors`

Comment: Not quite sure why you're using 3rd party io apis - Java can do all that quite easily, but as far as your point 3. is concerned, then that is simply a multipart container for the upload. Whatever has downloaded the attached has probably got it wrong, if it was uploaded as multipart

Comment: @KJ thanks for replying..can you help me with how to achieve this "ou need to inspect exactly what baggage is added by transportation, and remove it from all transfers by only transfer binary content without text"